# Are there downsides of using events in Blazor to handle SignalR notifications?

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr, .net-6.0

We have a Blazor app that receives notifications from SignalR (.NET 6).

Everything works well, but we noticed that each component establishes new connection with SignalR. So if we have 3 components on one page, there are 3 connections.

We experimented a bit, and created a singleton in Blazor that is receiving all notifications, and depending on message it will raise an event. So now we have only one connection to SignalR from Blazor because components are reacting on events.

Are there any problems in the long run if we do it like this?

Comment: Is this Blazor Server? If so, how do you handle multiple users? Singleton classes are shared among all users in a Blazor Server application.

Comment: @Lex it is Blazor web assembly. Every notification for that user is received by singleton and then that singleton just trigers events